# Max value from core data attribute of different entities

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have three entities in my core data modal, `A`, `B`, `C`. Each has a `createdAt` date.

What is the quickest way to access the most recent `createdAt` date, regardless of the entity type? Can I do something like:

(note: `fetchobjects`... is a just shorthand method to run a execute request)

```
NSArray *allAs = [context fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"A"];
NSArray *allBs = [context fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"B"];
NSArray *allCs = [context fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"C"];

NSArray *allObjects = [[allAs arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:allBs] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray: allCs]

NSDate *latestDate = [allObjects valueForKeyPath:@"@max.createdAt"];
```

Or is this considered risky (given that I am relying on the name of the attribute being the same in different entities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step can be optimized. Instead of fetching *all* objects of each entity, fetch only the most recent `createAt` value (per entity):

- add a sort descriptor to the fetch request that sorts descending by `createdAt`,
- set the `fetchLimit` to 1,
- set the `resultType` to `NSDictionaryType`,
- set the `propertiesToFetch` to `@[@"createdAt"]`.

The advantage is that the sorting by date is done on the SQLite level, instead of loading all objects into the managed object context and firing faults to get the `createdAt` attribute, so this should be faster and less memory intensive.

The `allObjects` array would then contain only 3 dictionaries (one for each entity).